# $\Bbb R$ as set of Dedekind cuts on $\Bbb Q$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, definition

> Let $A,B\in\Bbb Q,\ \ A < B$ if $A\leq B\ \land \ A \neq B$
>
> Let $\preceq$ be a ordering of a set $A$, and $B \subsetneqq A$.
>
> $B$ is initial segment of $A$ under $\preceq $ if $(\forall a \in A, \forall b \in B)(a \preceq b \to a \in B )$

---

The following definitions are correct:

> Let $\leq$ be an ordering of $\Bbb Q$, and $B \subsetneqq\Bbb Q$.

$B$ is Dedekind cut on $\mathbb{Q}$ if $B$ initial segment of $A$ under $\leq$ and $\forall C \in B, \exists D \in B (C < D)$

$\Bbb R:=\{B \subsetneqq \Bbb Q|B\text{ is Dedekind cuts on }\Bbb Q\}\ ?$

??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to know?

Comment: I want to know if the definitions of Dedekind cut and $\mathbb{R}$ are written  correctly..

Comment: Yep, these are correct. Think of Dedekind cuts on $\Bbb Q$ as sets of the form $S_{\alpha } = \{x \in \Bbb Q: x \lt \alpha \}$, where $\alpha \in \Bbb R$. The above definition is the identification $S_{\alpha } = \alpha$.

Comment: @walcher, thansk soo much! :)

Comment: @Invisible: Is there a shortage of new questions that need editing, that you decided to edit this one?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, no, I apologize for bumping up an old question. I was reading a relatively new, related question and I wanted to link some older to it I found. Some parts of this post weren't quite readable. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Invisible: you have edited [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488741/72031) also. Please do not bump old question unnecessarily.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, I apologize, I'll be more careful and responsible.