# Is $e^{\ln\left({\lim_{x \to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}}\right)}=e^{\lim_{x\to 0}\ln{(1+x)^{1/x}}}$? If so, why?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I am trying to follow a mathematical proof in [yahoo answers](http://ca.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110928001330AAZ6gKX), but I am not
understanding one of the steps that is implying that:

$$e^{\ln\left({\lim\limits_{x\to 0}(1+x)^{1/x}}\right)} = e^{\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\ln{(1+x)^{1/x}}}$$

What limit properties can be used to arrive at that equivalence?

Comment: both limits don't exist ?

Comment: Normally you can bring the limit inside the function itself. In real analys those limit laws are rigorously proven. in your case the answer to the limit is zero if you consider x→0+ that's a one sided limit

Comment: @imranfat no that is not normally. This is the case when your function is for example continuous

Comment: @Ted Because $\log$ is continuous on its domain. To assert the equality, however, you need both limits to exist.

Comment: In the example, you have $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (1+x)^{1/x} \neq 0$, so the continuity of the logarithm makes it okay. In yours, you have the problem that $\ln 0$ doesn't exist.

Comment: I think (I hope) the author is considering x→0+ That gives negative infinity in the e-power. Otherwise this limit indeed does not exist and my earlier statement is not valid either.

Comment: I see, so the generalization I made is wrong. But the specific use for lim_{x \to 0} (1+x)^(1/x) is correct

Comment: I'll rephrase my question, because my assumption makes the question confusing.

Comment: Yes, Ted, that limit does exist. Do you know what it is?

Comment: It is supposed to be e.. but I don't understand why the proof does what I illustrate in the equivalence.